# Open specific tab and launch a specific url in uiwebview when receive a push notification

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

i am developing an app that will receive Push notifications and when user hits view on notification, app launches and there are 3 uitabs in it and indexed as 0,1 and 2. My required tab, when notification received is second one whose index is 1. And when tab 1 openes it will detect that if this tab is open in response of a push notification then `UIWebview` will launch a different `URL`. Otherwise it will act as default. I am posting all my code please help me with this. Thanks in advance :)

Here is my `didReceiveRemotenotification` method, I am creating and saving a integer as a flag to make decision.
 - AppDelegate.m

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    int flg = 1;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:flg forKey:@"flagvlu"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
}
```

then it loads app and open first view which is Main.m
 - Main.m

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pushNotificationReceived) name:@"pushNotification" object:nil];
}
-(void)pushNotificationReceived{
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

and it passes app to next tab(Required.m) which is my required tab. in which i have a uiwebview.

Required.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [self doYourStuff];
  [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)doYourStuff{
  int flg = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"flagvlu"];
   if (flg == 1) {
     [webPage reload];
     [webPage loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
     flg = 0;
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:flg forKey:@"flagvlu"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
   }
   else if(flg == 0){
     [webPage reload];
     [webPage loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"]]];
   }
}
```

*Now the the problem is that app receives a notification and when user taps on view, it launches app and opens required tab perfectly but not launching desired `URL` in `webview`. :( please help i am new in objective c development.

Comment: Which controller is loading on tab index and how you are loading that controller?

Comment: Required.m viewcontroller is the one which has uiwebview. and i am loading it from Main.m when app launches because Required.m is my second tab(index 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing what you want is calling `doYourStuff` in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

`viewDidLoad` is called on view creation, typically when the view is added as a subview to another view.

`viewWillAppear` is called when the view becomes visible.

So, `viewDidLoad` is called when you populate your tab bar; `viewWillAppear` is called when you make that view visible (i.e., by tapping on its tab bar icon).

A better approach to `viewWillAppear` would be, IMO, using the [tab bar delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController%3adidSelectViewController%3a):

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

   if (<viewController is Required.m>)
       [(Required.m*)viewController doYourStyff];
}
```

which is called exactly once each time you tap on a tab bar item.

Answer (score 0):

Try This without using NSNotificationCenter.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{


        int flg = 1;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:flg forKey:@"flagvlu"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

   UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
   tabb.selectedIndex = 1;

}
```

now right **doYourStuff** in viewwillappear method.